# Where can I find a reference or a book to understand the terms used in Intel intrinsics descriptions?

Tags: assembly, intel, intrinsics

I'm studying to get a master's degree in CS and want (and need) to learn to use Intel intrinsics. However, the new intrinsics reference page, while being awesome per se, is full of specific lingo, which, as far as I understand, is related to assembly coding. The optimization reference manual uses descriptions composed of pretty much the same terms.

To give you an  example:

```
Unpack and interleave single-precision (32-bit) floating-point elements from the high half of each 128-bit lane in a and b

Blend packed single-precision (32-bit) floating-point elements from a and b using control mask imm
```

Pack what into which form? Why pack at all? What is interleave? What is blend? Which lanes? And so on.

I have tried to google using queries like "assembly/ intrinsics interleave/blend/pack", to no avail.

Where did you learn that kind of stuff from? Please note that I'm not looking for someone to explain me the specific terms above, there are many more of them out there. What I'm looking for is where to find a guide or a book, and what kind of guide or book it would be, that would give me an understanding of those seemingly "jargon" Intel terms.

Also, please note: this is not homework. We don't have such a course here, but I need and want to learn this stuff one day, myself.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Probably you will get help on `Quora(quora.com)`...

Comment: hey. This is Off topic, as it's asking for a book or off-site resource. Whether it's homework or not is moot... this will bring opiniated answers with "this book is better than this" or "don't use this, my book is better" etc

Comment: Excuse me, I'm looking for a way to understand these terms. What is off-topic? Is this not about programming? Is this politics? Or what?

Comment: @Patrice I'll bet you it won't. This kind of question is considered off-topic because it **can** bring this sort of answer, but this one would not if allowed to stay.

Comment: @PascalCuoq I have to be honest, I don't know intel intrinsics. I just saw the question on the main page and figured I'd pop in to say this, so that Semen can maybe fix it.

Comment: Once again, I'm asking here because there are many experienced programmers who have already walked this path present on this forum, and I'd like to know what their experience with this area of programming was.

Comment: All instructions are explained in vol 2 of [Intel's manual](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html). The manual also includes descriptions and figures of interleaving vector operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vocabulary used in intrinsics comes straight from the name of the assembly instructions each of them is translated to. In particular, “packed” is used in opposition to “scalar”, where a scalar instruction operates on one value and a packed one operates on a vector of as many values fit the register (say, 128 bits).

Look for a description of the instructions listed in, say, [this list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_SIMD_Extensions). I won't recommend any of them because rules. One source posted in the comments below the question is [Intel](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html), but from experience, links to Intel's website become dead every six months. You may have to google again “Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer Manuals” if you are reading this in the future.